Is the following generalization of the monotone convergence theorem correct?
Throughout the post we are working on a measure space $(X,\Sigma,\mu)$ and I abbreviate
$$\int_X f \text{d}\mu \ \ \text{ as }\ \ \int f.$$

I was wondering if the following generalization of the Monotone Convergence Theorem holds:
Theorem: let $f_n$ be a sequence of measurable functions $X\to [-\infty,\infty]$ such that

$f_n\to f$ for some measurable function $f$.
$f_n\le f$ for all $n$.
$\overline{\lim}\int f_n^- < \infty.$

Then
$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\int f_n = \int \lim_{n\to\infty}f_n = \int f.$$

What I know. Recently, I've read a couple of generalizations of the MCT:
Theorem 1: let $f_n:X\to[0,\infty]$ be a sequence of measurable functions such that

$f_n\to f$ for some measurable $f$.

$f_n\le f$ for all $n$.


Then
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\int f_n = \int\lim_{n\to\infty} f_n = \int f.$$
Proof: see here.
Theorem 2: let $f_n:X\to[-\infty,\infty]$ be a sequence of measurable functions such that

$f_n\to f$ for some measurable $f$.

$f_n\le f_{n+1}$ for all $n$.

$\int f_n$ is defined and greater than $-\infty$ for all $n$.


Then
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\int f_n = \int\lim_{n\to\infty} f_n = \int f.$$
Proof: see here (last paragraph).

My attempt.
Proof (of Theorem): the idea is to justify each of the following equalities
$$\int f 
\stackrel{1}{=} 
\int f^+ - \int f^- 
\stackrel{2}{=} 
\int \lim_{n\to\infty}f^+_n - \int \lim_{n\to\infty}f^-_n
\stackrel{3}{=} 
\lim_{n\to\infty}\int f_n^+ - \lim_{n\to\infty}\int f_n^-
\stackrel{4}{=} 
\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\int f_n^+ - \int f_n^-\right)
\stackrel{5}{=} 
\lim_{n\to\infty}\int f_n
$$
Equality $(1)$ follows by definition. For $(2)$, we note that
$$f_n\to f \iff f_n^+ \to f^+ \text{ and } f_n^- \to f^-.$$
For $(3)$ we argue
$$
\tag{Eq}
\int f^\pm = \int \underline{\lim} \ f_n^\pm  \stackrel{*}{\leq} \underline{\lim} \int f_n^\pm \leq \overline{\lim} \int f_n^\pm \leq \int f^\pm
$$
where $(*)$ uses Fatou's lemma. For $(4)$ let
$$a_n := \int f_n^+, \ \ \ \ b_n := \int f_n^-.$$
$(\text{Eq})$ implies that both $a_n$ and $b_n$ converge to $a$ and $b$ in $[0,\infty]$ respectively. The third hypothesis forces $b<\infty$, allowing us to write
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n - \lim_{n\to\infty}b_n \stackrel{4}{=} \lim_{n\to\infty}(a_n-b_n).$$
Equality $(5)$ follows by definition.

Is the proof correct?

Edit:  previously the third condition of Theorem asked only for $\int f_n>-\infty$ for every $n$. As Daniel mentioned, such condition is insuficient as per the counterexample
$$f_n = \chi_{[0,n]}-\chi_{[n,2n]} \ \ \ \ \text{ and } \ \ \ \ f = \chi_{[0,\infty)}.$$
The error here occurs in the term between equalities $(3)$ and $(4)$  of the proof, where
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \int f^+_n - \lim_{n\to\infty} \int f^-_n = \infty - \infty$$
is undefined. I've strengthened the third condition to (hopefully) prevent this and rewritten the proof for clarity.

As far as I can tell, $f_n = \chi_{[0,n]} - \chi_{[n,2n]}$ and $f = \chi_{[0,\infty)}$ satisfies the hypotheses but not the conclusion.  Unless I'm missing something.

I think what makes the example by @DanielSchepler fail is that you don't have $f_n \leq f \implies f_n^{-} \leq f^{-}$, so applying monotone convergence individually fails. Maybe you need $\vert f_n \vert \leq \vert f \vert$ to fix it?

@a_student you're right. I'm not properly using the second hypothesis. I'll check later.
